# Jquery make countdown

Tags: jquery

I am making a "countdown" but when it reached 0 it counts in minus; -1 -2 and so on. I want to make i stop at 0.

I have: "days ,hours ,minutes and seconds"

When everything is 00:00:00:00 i want it to stop.

Help :D

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){  

    function makeTimer() {

    var endTime = new Date("September 5, 2016 10:50:50 UTC+02:00");
    var endTime = (Date.parse(endTime)) / 1000;

    var now = new Date();
    var now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

    var timeLeft = endTime - now;

    var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400); 
    var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));

    if (hours < "10") { hours = "0" + hours; }
    if (minutes < "10") { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
    if (seconds < "10") { seconds = "0" + seconds; }    

    $("#days").html(days + "<span>Days</span>");
    $("#hours").html(hours + "<span>Hours</span>");
    $("#minutes").html(minutes + "<span>Minutes</span>");
    $("#seconds").html(seconds + "<span>Seconds</span>");

    }  

    setInterval(function() { makeTimer(); }, 1000);

    });  

    </script>
```

Comment: Check when `days`, `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` are `0`, then stop the interval

Comment: Check the one I posted to you. It should work. The example is working.

Comment: Resolved, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the `timeLeft` is less than or equal to 0.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    var timer = null;

    function makeTimer() {

        var endTime = new Date("September 5, 2016 19:50:50 UTC+02:00"),
            endTime = (Date.parse(endTime)) / 1000,
            now = new Date(),
            now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000),
            timeLeft = endTime - now;
       if(timeLeft > 0){
            var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400),
                hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600),
                minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60),
                seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));
           if (hours < "10") { hours = "0" + hours; }
           if (minutes < "10") { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
           if (seconds < "10") { seconds = "0" + seconds; }    

           $("#days").html(days + "<span>Days</span>");
           $("#hours").html(hours + "<span>Hours</span>");
           $("#minutes").html(minutes + "<span>Minutes</span>");
           $("#seconds").html(seconds + "<span>Seconds</span>");

      }else{
       clearInterval(timer);
       $("#seconds").html("<span>00Seconds</span>");
      }  
}
timer = setInterval(function() { makeTimer(); }, 1000);
```

})

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69ax5j4L/

Comment: Didnt work :C Tried direct copy aswell, i think i must have some syntax mistake..

Answer (score 1):

put the check like this:

```
var days = (timeLeft > 0)? Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400):0;
```

Keep the same condition for hours, mins, secs

To stop the timer:

```
if(days <> 0 && hours <>0 && minutes <>0 && seconds <>0 )
{
  setInterval(function() { makeTimer(); }, 1000);

    });
}
```

Comment: Didnt make it stop :C

Comment: well it made the days stop

Comment: Yes, you need to write the same condition for hours, min and sec. and stop calling the function when everything is 0

Comment: like this?
var days = (timeLeft > 0)? Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400):0;
var hours = (timeLeft > 0)? Math.floor(timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 36000:0;
var minutes = (timeLeft > 0)? Math.floor(timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60):0;
var seconds = (timeLeft > 0)? Math.floor(timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)))0;

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (now <= endTime){
      var timeLeft = endTime - now;
   }
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

I was using this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/fqPqS/349/

Just add to your code this lines:

```
var current = new Date();
if (current > endTime) {
    clearInterval(interval); 
}
```

And also change this:

```
 var interval = setInterval(makeTimer, 1000);
```